# Get the integer inside the URL in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I am reading a web page and the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is "http://example.com/term/11,23". How can I use [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) to get ONLY the integer in the URL?

Comment: Is this a Drupal site ? You could use function `arg` to get the parameter. // http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6

Comment: Yes, it is a Drupal site, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$str = 'http://example.com/term/11,23';
echo end(explode('/', $str));
```

**Result:**

```
11,23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com/term/11,23';
preg_match_all('#(\d+)#', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches); //outputs array([0]=>11,[1]=>23)
?>
```